# Bar plot with polar coordinates, adjust for tapering in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to create a scoring plot, like those you often see in role-playing games, with positive and negative scores, using ggplot.

To do this I use `geom_col` and `coord_polar`. The problem is that the bars are not rectangles but trapezoids, as expected since the whole plotting space coordinates system is deformed.

[image]

Is it possible to adjust for this in order to have proper uniform bars (and add some space at the center of the plot to avoid overlapping)?

Bonus request: instead of a circular grid, is it possible to have a polygonal one, based on the number of values on the x-axis?

Comment: Please share sample of your data using `dput()` (not `str` or `head` or picture/screenshot) so others can help. 
See more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use line segments instead of bars. The thickness would then depend on the size you choose, rather than the coordinate system:

```
# sample dataset
set.seed(333)
n.dim = 9
df <- data.frame(
  x = paste("attribute", seq(1, n.dim), sep = "."),
  score = rnorm(n.dim)
)

ggplot(df,
       aes(x = x, y = score, 
           xend = x, yend = 0,
           col = score >= 0)) +
  geom_segment(size = 15) +                 # adjust size for different bar thickness
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.1, 0)) +  # increase space at plot centre
  coord_polar() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
```

[image: plot]

I think a polygon grid (rather than a circular one) would be more harder to interpret, as distance from plot centre no longer has a one-to-one relationship with the y-axis values. (See illustration below) It's probably possible to hack something that resembles a polygon grid in ggplot, but I've yet to see any such implementation myself.

[image: plot]